Oracle: How to capture forall save exceptions using while loop method
In oracle,Usually when we use forall save exceptions to capture error occurring records through bulk load, we will use for loop to iterate the SQL%bulk exceptions and capture the error records..there is a requirement to use while loop instead of for loop in exception block to capture SQL%bulk exceptions. Please could someone post working code on how to use while loop for capturing SQL%bulk exceptions?
i tried with for loop to capture SQL%bulk exceptions with error code and error index. But need to kno, how to use while loop to achieve this

Do you mean something like this?
SQL> create table t ( x int, check ( x > 0 ) );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> declare
  2
  3    bulk_bind_err EXCEPTION;
  4    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (bulk_bind_err, -24381);
  5
  6    type numlist is table of number;
  7    l_rows numlist;
  8
  9  begin
 10    l_rows := numlist(1,2,3,-1,-2,-3,4,5,6,-4,-5);
 11
 12    forall i in 1 .. l_rows.count save exceptions
 13      insert into t values (l_rows(i));
 14
 15
 16  exception
 17    when bulk_bind_err then
 18      declare
 19         l_index int := 1;
 20      begin
 21         while l_index < sql%bulk_exceptions.count
 22         loop
 23            dbms_output.put_line(sql%bulk_exceptions(l_index).error_index ||','||sql%bulk_exceptions (l_index).error_code);
 24            l_index := l_index + 1;
 25         end loop;
 26      end;
 27  end;
 28  /
4,2290
5,2290
6,2290
10,2290

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


Thanks Connor, it is working as expected
